# Pod is using node group role instead of service account in aws eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am using a service account with a role assigned to it using OIDC. I opened shell in the pod and checked current role,

[image]

but my service is doing the same thing but it is using node role,

[image]

### Versions of Java SDK

- aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.505

Comment: what version of AWS SDK are you using in your java code?

Comment: @RezaNasiri I am now using 1.12.106 and it is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The containers in your pods must use an AWS SDK version that supports
> assuming an IAM role via an OIDC web identity token file.

Check if you meet the minimum requirement for [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) is 1.9.220, for [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) is 1.12.200.

Comment: I am now using 1.12.106 and it is working now.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-minimum-sdk.html